# How to make Borders just on all of records on database (PHPexcel)

Tags: phpexcel

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tutorial"); 
$result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM keluarga");
$nomor=9; /*diganti menjadi dua karena baris pertama dipakai untuk header*/
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $nomor++;
    $sheet  ->setCellValue ( "D".$nomor, $row["nama"] );
    $sheet  ->setCellValue ( "E".$nomor, $row["alamat"] );
    $sheet  ->setCellValue ( "F".$nomor, $row["ayah"] );
    $sheet  ->setCellValue ( "G".$nomor, $row["ibu"] );
    $sheet  ->setCellValue ( "H".$nomor, $row["hobi"] );
}
```

i want to ask , how to make border just to all record....
if data just 3 record , the border just in these 3 record....
sorry if my english speak bad , coz i'm from indonesian....
please answer , or send to my email thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

keep track of the top-right and bottom-left cells that you use for your dataset (`'D9:H'.$nomor` for your highest value of `$nomor`); then set the border style for that range using `allborders` as described in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#styling-cell-borders)

```
$styleArray = [
    'borders' => [
        'allborders' => [
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
        ],
    ],
];

$objWorksheet->getStyle('D9:H'.$nomor)
    ->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```